I am trying to find a manga where the mc is reincarnated as an extra
I have read a manga a long time ago where the comic was in 4koma-style I think. He lived in a world that operated on manga rules/tropes, and he commented a lot about it. The most biggest one was where he was a faceless character, and was the older brother of a person with facial features who is an important character.
The most recent plot I remember was of how the younger brother of the protagonist was complaining about the actions of his older brother to his friends.

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

@LogicDictates It was in full colour.

What type of world was the MC reincarnated to? Medieval fantasy?

@LogicDictates It was normal modern world. He was living in Japan as a faceless character.
